# ios App for Sleep/Wake Unlock?

Tags: iphone, ios, unlock

The normal way to unlock the iphone after waking up is to enter a 4 digit code. Does Apple offer some sort of iOS method for replacing this unlock screen with a custom programmed one?

I'd like to replace the 4 digit unlock mechanism with the android style "connect-the-points" unlock method. Such that when the user wakes the device up the user has to connect the points instead of entering a 4 digit code.

Does anyone know if this is possible on a technical level and if it is allowed by Apple?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible with an un-jailbroken iOS SDK

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I already supposed this. But do you have some sort of source the confirms your statement?

Comment: Well, the iOS docs don't exactly have an extensive list of what you can't do, only what you can.  There is no part of the SDK related to allowing you to mess with this part of iOS, you can see in the docs where you react to and detect if the screen is locked.  The launchpad core of the iOS just isn't available for this sort of finagling - apps only operate as apps, not replacing parts of iOS.

Answer (score 2):

> 2.4 Apps that include undocumented or hidden features inconsistent with the description of the app will be rejected
>   2.5
>   Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
>   
> *Source [iOS App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#functionality)*

As Andrew explained, it's not possible in the public SDK, there are no public APIs to replace this functionality.